# UIWebView Content is not resizable by user

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, uiwebview

I'm struck over this little issue and just can't figure a way out. My apologies and gratitude.

Description:

an UIView with fullscreen UIWebView targeted for iPhone programmatically loads a web page using `viewDidLoad` method. When running the app into the simulator UIWebView is displayed, the web page loaded, but no pinching is allowed. Thus, I can move around the page, but I can't resize with multigesture.

Details:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.someurl.it";

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

   webView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
   webView.autoresizingMask=YES;
   webView.multipleTouchEnabled=YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the proper property to set to allow [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s to interpret pinch-to-zoom events is called`scalesPageToFit`.  Setting an `autoresizingMask` is a hint to the auto-rotational layout mechanism in UIView of where a view should be positioned in the new coordinate space of the given device.

Comment: Thank you so much, also for the insight.
By the way, `autoresizingMask` is not supposed to afflict the web page content, but only the UIWebView container to fit changes in device orientation, is it?

Answer (score 2):

Just insert this line of code along with the other properties you set for the webview:

`webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;`

Comment: Thank you so much, yesterday night I was probably going mad about this.